# Is there a TOM.Net API to find whether a particular page been already published to a specific publication target?

Tags: 2013, publishing, custom-resolver, dynamic-publishing

I have a requirement to skip publishing of pages or components if the same is already been published to that target. Am trying to write some logic in resolver to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've answered below, but next time to avoid the risk of not getting good answers or being downvoted for not showing any effort on your own behalf do state in your question what you've tried :) cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  Here you go:

```
    public void Resolve(IdentifiableObject item, ResolveInstruction instruction, PublishContext context, col.ISet<ResolvedItem> resolvedItems)
    {
        //... do your logic
        Page p = item as Page;
        bool isPublishedToCurrentTarget = PublishEngine.IsPublished(p, context.PublicationTarget);
        //... do more of your logic
    }
```